# Help with PHPExcel Library and mySQL data from a table

Tags: mysql, phpexcel

I have this script

```
$query = "SELECT id,last_name,first_name FROM users WHERE tmima_id='6'";
$result = @mysql_query($query); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $i = 3;

    $emp_id = $row['id'];

    $cell = 'A'.$i;

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
       ->setCellValue($cell, $row['last_name']. $row['first_name']);
    $i++;
}
```

But in the .xls file it prints only one user. Why id doesnt print all of the users ? W

Thanks in advance.

---

I make the change you said with $sheet

```
$query = "SELECT id,last_name,first_name FROM users WHERE tmima_id='6'";
 $result = @mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $i = 3;

   $emp_id = $row['id'];

   $cell = 'A'.$i;


   $sheet->setCellValue($cell, $row['last_name']. $row['first_name']);


   $i++;
 }
```

But it still prints out only one record. And yes when i run the query in phpmyadmin it returns more than one record.

How can i print out data from mySql table.. What is going wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one result and that `$i` is incrementing properly? Also why keep resetting the sheet index do it once outside the loop and store it in `$sheet` or something similar, then you can just call `$sheet->setCellValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is because you are using a unique identifier (WHERE tmima_id='6'). It is only finding the results for that one unique identifier and displaying that.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$i is being reset to row 3 every loop. Set $i=3; **before** the while loop, not inside it.