# Fetch multiple rows from a table and write it into excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm using phpexcel to fetch data from a table in mysql db and write it into an excel sheet. 
Suppose my query is fetching 3 rows with below fields for some condition,
UserName, email, Location. Excel sheet should look like:

```
UserName    Email       Location
ABC         abc@.com     NY
PQR         pqr@.com     CO
XYZ         xyz@.com     CA
```

Rows need to be dynamically added into excel sheet if the query is fetching n number of rows based on the condition.

Comment: So... what have you tried so far... have you tried searching this site? This question has been asked multiple times...

Comment: Have you looked at all the examples that come with phpexcel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480963/help-with-phpexcel-library-and-mysql-data-from-a-table

Comment: So far I was fetching only one row using Group by and having condition as per the requirement. From the result set, I'm mapping the column headers into excel cell values. Now, I need to add multiple rows in excel sheet and the result set will be more than one row, obviously I can't sett cell values in excel. So pls. advise how to add multiple rows in the excel dynamically..Thanks, Krishna

Comment: @user2138589 - show some code

Comment: @Mark Baker, I looked into the link given by you and using below code
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("Multiple_rows.xls");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultqry)) {
    $i = 1;
 $cell1 = 'A'.$i;
 $cell2 = 'B'.$i;
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell1, $row['User_name']);
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell2, $row['emailaddr']);
 $i++;

But it is fetching only one row, but result set has 3 rows. Please advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("Multiple_rows.xls"); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

$i = 1; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultqry)) { 
    $cell1 = 'A'.$i; 
    $cell2 = 'B'.$i; 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell1, $row['User_name']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell2, $row['emailaddr']); 
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you very much for your help and it worked! Thanks once again :)